# Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to int?

Tags: codeigniter, session

```
<?php 
$total=$this->db->query("SELECT status FROM `join` WHERE ev_id =34 AND id =12");
?>
```

I need the Result in int

Comment: Its unclear can you add some brief regarding your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after query

```
 $query = $this->db->query($total);
```

then get

```
print_r($query->results());
```

you will get it .